# Trying to find xpath for ancestor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to write an xpath for the screenshot below. I tried

```
("//*[@id='subjects_grid']/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/label[@class='switch']/ancestor::td/a[@data-subjectid='425']")
```

but the console was not recognizing after td. I also tried

```
("//tr[@class='subject-status-off']/td[1]/a[@data-subjectid='425']/td/label")
```

but the console was not pointing to element after `a[@data-subjectid='425']`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifzFK.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. This includes HTML.

Comment: Have you tried something simple like a CSS selector, `tr.subject-status-off > td > a.link-name`? You might even be able to get away with just `tr.subject-status-off a`. Or even a simple XPath like `//a[contains(text(), 'Reading')]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//*[@id='subjects_grid']/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/label[@class='switch']/ancestor::td/a[@data-subjectid='425']")
```

in the above locator you are going from parent td[2] back to itself and then trying to find the child 'a' there is no child in td[2]

```
//*[@id='subjects_grid']/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/label[@class='switch']/ancestor::tr/td/a[@data-subjectid='425']"
```

Try the above locator, **here it finds the label and goto the parent 'tr' adn then navigates td/a**

Note, if data-subjectid is unique you can just use

```
//a[@data-subjectid='425']
```